# Confusion with python's feedparser speed, it's very fast on the command line but slow when im deploying

Tags: python, django, feedparser

```
feed = feedparser.parse("http://someyoutubeurl")
video_data = feed.entries[0]
# Adding the data to a dict, etc...
```

This line of code when typed on my python command line instantly runs and finishes. But when i'm deploying feedparser on my django web server, the process literally takes like 10 seconds to complete. Something must be very wrong.

I even tested using the same exact youtube video, and the speed difference was still there!

Do any of you have ideas? Thanks

Comment: Does your web server have the sgmllib module available? If not (which, admittedly, would be odd), feedparser falls back to its own pure-Python implementation which is quite a bit slower.

Comment: There might be problems with the DNS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this counts as an answer, but generally there are multiple reasons I see:

- The hardware of your webserver might not be as powerful as your desktop, so downloading and parsing simply takes longer. If possible you can try the same line of code in your webserver python shell and measure the performance. Downloading depends mainly on your connections speed, parsing mainly on your CPU and partly RAM (depending on the size of the feed).
- If you running this line of code within Django there will be a slightly bigger delay than when you run if from plain python shell, simple because every action has to go through the Django framework.

Comment: I just ran the same line of code on a web server, and it was very very slow! I'm using webfaction, not sure if that has sgmllib or not, but im sharing the server with like 30 other people so that probably affects speed

Comment: Yeah, webfaction is kind of slow so I heard. Never used it myself though. If your site is just a blog or something simple and small its probably a good host though.

Comment: Eh, I think I need something much faster, do you have any suggestions? I do have an IIS7 windows server 2008 machine at home I can use (works with django using some 3rd party software called helicon zoo), but i'd prefer to host with a company

Comment: I wouldn't suggest a windows machine as Django/Python hosting. I didn't really deploy at a high-scale yet (my private VPN is on a german hosting provider). You should check https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoFriendlyWebHosts. If you don't want to bother with sysadmin tasks I would suggest you to use some PaaS though like http://www.heroku.com/, https://gondor.io/, etc.. Heroku for example will initially cost you nothing, but when you want to scale up its more expensive than self-managed servers. Though you save lots of time and money not doing the sysadmin work!!!